# Nodal voltage magnitude properties of electricity distribution networks

Tags: power-supply, power-engineering, stability, low-voltage, distribution-network

I am wondering how to know about an electric bus according to its measured voltage magnitudes (possibly and its corresponding real power injection profile).

Following assumptions can be made:

1. One three-phase-four-wire low-voltage radial power distribution network with laterals.
2. Residential load only.
3. There is no transformer or voltage regulator (because I heard they were not common).
4. We know the phase of measurements. But most likely, we only have those for one phase. We have measurements from different phases.
5. We may have real power injections (same phase, same bus) at the same time.
6. We may have measurements from multiple buses with same time indices.

Then, if I give you some nodal measurements from some buses in the same phase, can you derive some information on these buses? The bus must show some characteristics because of its "position" in a radial electrical network.

---

Sept 1, 2020: I found a concept called `V/V0 index`: assuming the bus voltage values (`V`) to be known from load flow or state estimation studies, new bus voltages (`V0`) are obtained solving a load flow for the system at an identical state but with all loads set to zero. The ratio `V/Vo` at each node yields a voltage stability map of the system, allowing for immediate detection of weak and effective countermeasure spots.

But there is no way for me to obtain load flow results, because **I only have nodal measurements**.

---

Sept 2, 2020: I found voltage magnitudes of a bus is larger than those of buses further away from the root, if there is no capacitor. For example bus 645 is closer to the root compared to bus 646 in the following `IEEE-1992-13` case.

---

Right now, I can think of one method to group buses. If I regress voltage magnitudes on real power injections, I have a slope, indicating how much effect real power have on the nodal voltage:

[image]

Then, if we have slopes from the same phase of two buses and slopes are really close, then we know they are most likely in the same branch. In `IEEE-1992-13` test case, I got following results for one phase:

```
632 11.819768711285295
670 11.820047039778458
671 11.821094186322632

633 11169.153693797027
634 1288.7489820261399

684 4460.569650713787
652 4508.958261689517

680 248273082537576.5

692 11.822712103994313
675 11.827380543736016
```

[image]

In my setting, we don't know the name of the bus. But based on the statistics, we can say `680` is not in the main branch, `684` and `652` are close to each other, etc.